# Appending a tuple to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having troubles appending a tuple to a pandas Dataframe inside a for loop. 
I initialized the Dataframe where all the tuples will be attached as follows:

`self.URM_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=["playlist_id", "track_id"])`

Then I enter a loop where I want to attach the tuple I'm creating at each iteration, I'm doing it in this way:

```
URM_test_tuple = pd.DataFrame({"playlist_id": [int(self.target_playlists_test[count])], "track_id": [playlist_tracks_list]}) 
self.URM_test.append(URM_test_tuple)
```

If I print `URM_test_tuple` I get a correct result, as follows:

```
     playlist_id   track_id
0        13317     [18940, 18902, 8892, 1365, 6806, 8972, 18944, ...
```

But when I'm printing `self.URM_test` during the bug I'm noticing it's empty and I'm getting this printed to console

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [playlist_id, track_id]
Index: []
```

Do you know what might be the bug in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The append method in pandas creates a new object as stated in the documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

You could try assigning the new object to URM_test in your loop

```
URM_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=["playlist_id", "track_id"])
URM_test_tuple = pd.DataFrame({"playlist_id": ['foo'], "track_id": ['bar']})
URM_test = URM_test.append(URM_test_tuple)
```